# File upload progressbar onclick event with mootools-form-upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mootools

I am using file upload in my current project. When I click browse button, the file will be uploaded automatically and read number of lines and display that details immediately. I finished this task.

But when I will uploaded large size of file it will take some time to upload. So I need to implement file uploading progress bar.

I used the the following example.

http://aryweb.nl/projects/mootools-form-upload/Demos/Upload.html

http://mootools.net/forge/p/form_upload

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        var upload = new Form.Upload('files', {
            onComplete: function(){
                alert('Completed uploading the Files');
            }
        });
        if (!upload.isModern()){
            // Use something like
        }
    });
</script>
```

This script working well.

But when I will click  submit button, that time will be displaying progress bar.

I need to change when I will click browse button that time will be display the progress bar. I don't know how to change.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mootools plugin javascript library that allows you to upload files and track the progress. It has little to do with PHP.

Since demo and documentation for it doesn't have progress tracking, if you look closely at https://github.com/arian/mootools-form-upload/blob/master/Source/Form.Upload.js then you'll see that progress doesn't have any callback in it..

```
onProgress: function(event){
            var loaded = event.loaded, total = event.total;
            progress.setStyle('width', parseInt(loaded / total * 100, 10).limit(0, 100) + '%');
        },
```

so you need to either

1. Use suggested HTML it expects (`<div class='progress'></div>`), OR
2. Add your custom behaviour by extending options it includes before that